# Machine code program using mips16 instructions

Tags: assembly, mips

I am trying to make a program that iterates the numbers from 1 to 10 and if the number is odd it adds 2 or if the number is even it multiplies it by 4. Then we make the sum of the elements and store it in the memory.
I am new at this and I don't have a fpga board so I don't know if the program does the right thing. Could someone please help me with any errors?

```
add $1,$0,$0       # i = 0, control 
addi $4,$0,10      # max numer of iterations
add $2,$0,$0       # memory index
add $5,$0,$0        # sum = 0
beq $1,$4,7         # 10 iterations? if not, continue
lw $3,1($2)        # in $3 current number
addi $1,$1,1       #verify if odd or even
beq $1,$0,3
addi $3,$3,2        # if odd $3 = $3 + 2
sw $3,1($2)        # update the number
j 13            #jump over the even part to the sum
par: sll $3,$3,2  #if even
sw $3,1($2)        # update the number
add $5,$5,$3        # add to sum
addi $1,$1,1       # next index i++
addi $2,$2,1        # increment memory value
j 4               # jump to the begining
sw $5,10($0)   #store the sum
```

Comment: Why don't you just test it in a simulator like SPIM or MARS?

Comment: You shouldn't need loads or stores except for 1 store at the end; it only takes a few registers for the current counter, the sum, and a couple temporaries.  Also, an offset of 1 byte is almost certainly wrong for `sw $3, 1($2)`.  If `$2` is a word-aligned pointer, `1 + $2` will be a misaligned address.